# What distribution is produced by the correlation of random values sampled uniformly?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, correlation, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to figure out what this distribution is so that I can calculate the exact probability of values close to 1 or -1 using its PDF:

[image: Histogram of values determined by the correlation between random variables]

as produced by the following code in R:

```r
random_length <- 20
random_vars <- matrix(runif(1000*random_length), 
                      nrow = random_length)
perf_cors <- cor(random_vars)
perf_cors <- perf_cors[!perf_cors==1] # Remove self-correlations
hist(perf_cors, breaks = seq(-1, 1, length.out=1000))
```

My original problem was to figure out the probability of getting a correlation above 0.95 just by chance for a sequence of 20 known values, which I approached by simulation here and can estimate as "very small". However, I'd like to expand this to longer/shorter lengths of random variables and correlation cutoffs higher/lower than 0.95, which means that I can't simulate everything and instead need the PDF of this distribution as a function of random variable vector length. The self-correlation matrix I use below is just a way to get a lot of "random" correlation values very quickly. Here's a couple more histograms with varying random variable vector lengths:

[image: more histograms]

as produced with the following R code:

```r
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
sapply(c(5, 10, 20, 50), function(random_length){
  random_vars <- matrix(runif(1000*random_length), 
                        nrow = random_length)
  perf_cors <- cor(random_vars)
  perf_cors <- perf_cors[!perf_cors==1] # Remove self-correlations
  hist(perf_cors, breaks = seq(-1, 1, length.out=1000), 
       main = paste("Random length =", random_length))
})
layout(1)
```

I've gotten close to estimating one using the beta distribution - the shape looked like a nice bell curve but the probability is zero for exactly 0 and 1 which made me think beta. Fiddling with the shape parameters (settling on alpha and beta as 10) gave me a pretty nice fit but I've only done this when the random variable vector length is 20 and the fit still isn't perfect.

[image: points plotted this time with a line on top]

created with the R code:

```r
random_length <- 20
random_vars <- matrix(runif(1000*random_length), 
                      nrow = random_length)
perf_cors <- cor(random_vars)
brks <- seq(-1, 1, length.out=1000)
cors_cut <- cut(perf_cors, breaks = brks)
cors_table <- table(cors_cut)
plot(head(brks, -1), cors_table/max(cors_table), yaxt="n", 
                     xlab = "", ylab="")
perf_curve <- dbeta(seq(0, 1, length.out=1000), shape1=5, shape2=5)^2
perf_curve <- dbeta(seq(0, 1, length.out=1000), shape1=10, shape2=10)
lines(brks, perf_curve/max(perf_curve), col="red", lwd=2)
```

I've already searched a bit on the site for similar questions, and found [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376869/correlation-of-random-variables) that doesn't provide a PDF and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/458341/what-distribution-does-the-mean-of-a-random-sample-from-a-uniform-distribution-f) that went straight over my head.

**Any advice for what distribution I'm looking at here?**

Comment: The density plots at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85977/919 should look familiar, because they provide analytical solutions to this question when the data are independently Normal.  They are indeed Beta distributions.  Because correlation coefficients are so closely related to average products, the Central Limit Theorem provides insight and helps explain why you see Beta distributions in the uniform case, too. I don't expect a nice analytic formula to exist--the integrals look too messy.